# Build separate lists of matching and non-matching files

Tags: linux, bash

```
<NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >
```

I want to search for files that contain the line above and save the matching files in `found_list.txt` and and non-matching files in `notfound_list.txt`. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
grep -rl <NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC > >> found_list.txt 
grep -vrl <NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC > >> notfound_list.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Quote and use the correct parameter:

```
grep -rl "<NAME = \$\$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >" >> found_list.txt
grep -rL "<NAME = \$\$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >" >> notfound_list.txt
```

Please note both lines differ in case of the second parameter.

**EDIT:** Escaped $ signs.

Comment: @ JL. Sanchez  => Not working .... it is showing like this "<NAME = 1123WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >" in place of $$ showing some number not fetching displaying could not found files